# Rails 4.2: Internal Server Error with Maximum file multiparts in content reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Just upgraded to Rails 4.2 and I get Internal Server Error on localhost and in production when trying to edit a model with multiple has_many objects. This is the message I see on the rails s console

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: Too many open files - Maximum file multiparts in content reached
```

The request does not even get to the controller i.e., I DO NOT see the usual following lines in rails s console

```
Started GET "/feeds/3/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 20:07:19 -0800
Processing by FeedsController#edit as HTML
......
......
```

Any clues?? Using Ruby 2.1.5 upgraded to 2.2 with no luck.

Comment: Getting the same thing here, Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0.

Comment: Rack 1.6.4 contains a fix for this.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It looks like the multipart limit was added in the Rails 4.2 version of Rack (https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/b0b5fb9467e6ed777d3eaf35afc81d758e308aab). The default is 128, which may be too little for your purposes, it was for mine. Setting the value to 0 in an initializer removes the limit and fixes the problem:

```
Rack::Utils.multipart_part_limit = 0
```

I would suggest tailoring the value until it fits your needs so your server doesn't run out of file handles. My app uses a massive form and setting it to 512 seemed to work for me.

Comment: Thank you Craig. Will test and mark your answer as accepted if it works. I do have a long form. The shorter forms work fine.

Comment: It looks to us like the patch that was introduced is counting one open file per form element, not just files. So if you have a nested form, you quickly run out of "files". Seems like a bad patch.

Comment: Rack 1.6.1 does NOT contain this fix.  Looks like that will be in the 1.7 release instead :(

Comment: Rack 1.6.4 contains a fix for this.

Comment: Hey i m facing the same problem,Where i can place this line?

Comment: @JigarBhatt I place it in config.ru, for reference

Answer (score 14):

You can also pass a Environment variable to the app, as you can see here(https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/8d21788798b521b97beb10047ebf593ddc0aaed2/lib/rack/utils.rb#L75).

`RACK_MULTIPART_PART_LIMIT=0 rails server`

Comment: But you should set both `RACK_MULTIPART_PART_LIMIT` and `RACK_MULTIPART_LIMIT` because of the code remark _RACK_MULTIPART_LIMIT was introduced by mistake and it will be removed in 1.7.0_

Comment: Hey i m facing the same problem,Where i can place this line?

Comment: @JigarBhatt you can set this env variables on the line that you execute your script.

For example: `RACK_MULTIPART_PART_LIMIT=0 ruby app.rb`

or you can export you variable an then run your script.
`export RACK_MULTIPART_PART_LIMIT=0 `

then 
`ruby app.rb`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there is a bug in Rack 1.6 where all HTML input elements get counted as an open file in a multipart form.  As others point out, you can change the limit to 0 to disable the feature, or bump the limit.

https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/814

Comment: This has been merged into 1.6.4 it appears