# On Rails 7, I am receiving an error when submitting large forms: 'Error during failsafe response: Maximum total multiparts in content reached'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

After upgrading to Rails 7 (from 5.2) I have been getting the following error when submitting large forms

`Error during failsafe response: Maximum total multiparts in content reached`

I initially though it was related to this error: [Rails 4.2: Internal Server Error with Maximum file multiparts in content reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773368/rails-4-2-internal-server-error-with-maximum-file-multiparts-in-content-reached), but setting the `multipart_part_limit` has no effect

Answer (score 3):

The answer was to add this into `config.ru`:

`Rack::Utils.multipart_total_part_limit = 0`

From the docs here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/main/README.md#multipart_total_part_limit

> multipart_total_part_limit The maximum total number of parts a request
> can contain of any type, including both file and non-file form fields.
>
> The default is 4096, which means that a single request can't contain
> more than 4096 parts.
>
> Set to 0 for no limit.
>
> Can also be set via the RACK_MULTIPART_TOTAL_PART_LIMIT environment
> variable.